# How to redirect in php with hidden link

Tags: php

I have a private link (External link) https://fantasy.premierleague.com/?autojoin-code=xxxxxxxxxx, I want the user to redirect from my site to this link after payment. And the user should not see the link for security reasons (link is static and I can't change it each time). How I can redirect the user to that page, Without access user to link?
it is possible?

I've tried to get content but it's not effective.

Comment: can we see some code?

Comment: It isn't possible to redirect a browser to a link that is hidden. Why would you even want to do that?

Comment: [header('Location: https://fantasy.premierleague.com/?autojoin-code=xxxxxxxxxx')](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: take a look at this https://www.siteground.com/kb/url_masking_with_htaccess/

Comment: @Sfili_81 i just used php get content

Comment: @Martin This is Join to Football fantasy league link , i want only paid users can join league

Comment: @RiggsFolly after redirect user still can access URL in the browser tabbar

Comment: You can't do security by hiding URLs. Since the browser has to connect to the URL, the user can find out what the browser is doing. The script at the destination URL needs to check that the user is valid. Set a session variable before redirecting, and check it in the target.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a file on server Eg: join-league.php and add a curl request code there for this link https://fantasy.premierleague.com/?autojoin-code=xxxxxxxxxx. After user make an successful payment just redirect them to this file join-league.php.